# Spawned Process Terminated in GP Startup Script

Tags: windows, group-policy, scripting, active-directory, startup-scripts

I have a Group Policy Startup Script which runs synchronously. I now need this script to run one process asynchronously. So far I have managed to get the spawned process running via the command below, however once the rest of the script finishes and the GP Startup Script "phase" finishes and the logon prompt is shown, my spawned process is terminated. Is there any way to have this process continue beyond the Startup Script phase?

```
cmd /c start spawned.bat
```

I guess the reason why it terminates is because the process was launched by the Startup Script process and when the parent process terminates so do its children.

PS I need it to be launched via the exisitng script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved in another way.

Comment: Can you provide just a wee bit of detail, for those who read this later?